# How can I declare a global integer and use it across my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I declare a global integer and use it across my app?

Answer (score 2):

```
//SomeFile.h
extern int n;

//SomeFile.m
int n;

//SomeOtherFile.m
#import "SomeFile.h"
```

Now you can use global n in your SomeOtherFile.m file

Comment: I have just tried this and it threw 12 errors concerning my variable. 

I tried 

CODE::

//otherviewcontroller.h

extern int lives;

//otherviewcotroller.m

lives = 5;

and I also use it here in several times.

//levelcleared.m
#import "otherviewcontroller.h"

score = lives * 1000; 

::END OF CODE

Comment: you didn't initialize correctly. use int lives = 5; in otherviewcontroller.m

Comment: tried that mate, it just throws a warning followed by the other 11 errors. Anybody else know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as a property in your application delegate and access your application delegate everywhere using this singleton :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Integer Global Variable for Complete iPhone Project/App**

For Declare/Define/Use a global variable follow these easy steps:-

1. Create a NSObject File with named "GlobalVars.h and .m" or as u wish
2. Declare your global variable in GlobalVars.h file after #import and before @implementation like-

   extern int Var_name;
3. initialize it in GlobalVars.m file after #import and before @implementation like-

   int Var_name = 0;
4. Now where you want to use this variable (in .m file) just import/inclue GlobalVars.h file in that all .h files, and you can access easily this variable as Globally.
5. Carefully follow these Steps and it'll work Surely.